# Strange JavaScript idiom - what does "/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})" do?

Tags: javascript, regex, function

John Resig wrote a nifty Class function, swanky. I'm trying to figure out what is going on, and have pretty much everything figured out except a single line:

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function () {xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

A couple things immediately jump to mind, first `xyz` is never initialized as a variable; so why then does this work? Second, why is it testing `/xyz/` against something that is not returning anything (no return statement). Unless there is some nifty properties of javascript I'm unaware of (which is possible, I fancy myself rather good at JS and can interpret most the code I come across it doesn't, however, mean I'm eve on the same Mt. Everest sized mountain that John Resig calls home).

For those curious, here is the full unedited code from john resigs site [John Resig Simple Javascript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/):

```
(function () {
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;

            // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
            // but on the super-class
            this._super = _super[name];

            // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
            // remove it when we're done executing
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);       
            this._super = tmp;

            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    function Class() {
      // All construction is actually done in the init method
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };

})();
```

Comment: .. reader (in)sanity check? :)

Comment: .. hmm I surrounded the code in <code> ... </code> tags, wonder why it butchered so badly (note &gt; .. &lt; don't evaluate to what I think they should oy, today is not my day.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is just a quick & dirty way to check if "function decompilation" works.

The `RegExp.prototype.test` method will take the argument and it will convert it to String, the `xyz` reference inside the function is never evaluated.

*Why would you have to check this?*

Because the `Function.prototype.toString` method returns an *implementation-dependent* representation of a function, and in some implementation, such older Safari versions, Mobile Opera, and some Blackberry browsers, they don't actually return anything useful.

Comment: so, isn't the `xyz` anonymous function body unnecessary?

Comment: @mykhal, `xyz` is what you are actually looking for, to know that *function decompilation* works properly. It is just checking that a the function converted to string, produces a string that contains the body of the function...

Comment: @CMS yep, i finally got it after a while.. )

Comment: Just to add a note: In order to make the test pass jslint it would have to be /var xyz/.test(function () { var xyz; }) ? /\b_super\b/ : /[\D|\d]*/; why \D|\d simple, one catches all numbers, the other catches everything else, it is equivalent to .* but that is considered 'insecure' because you aren't defining limits. Took me forever to realize what they meant by insecure '.'. Voted you up, and also marked as answer, thank you very much CMS.

Comment: @CMS: so if you change the regex `xyz` to something else, do you also need to change it in the function body?

Comment: @vol7ron: The regex should try to match something *recognizable* from the `FunctionBody`, remember that we are just trying to check if `Function.prototype.toString` does the job.

Comment: So `(function(){var abc;}).toString().match(/abc/)` would do the same? That's a neat 'trick'.

Comment: What I don't get in the code is why he even needs the `fnTest`. Isn't `typeof foo === "function"` good enough for all cases?

Comment: @trinithis, well, `typeof foo == 'function` would work, but the problem is that you will end up wrapping every single function object, even if they doesn't use `_super`. Resig is just inspecting every function, to see if it uses in its body the `_super` identifier. If `_super` appears on the body of the function, then he wraps that one into another function, in which he first exposes the "super" of the "class", by assigning `this._super`. Then he executes the original function that was inspected, and was proven to use `_super`, and finally he restores the value of `this._super`...

Comment: @Akidi We found this code with the `var xyz;` variant in our codebase a year or so ago, but we assumed it was just trying to make debugging easier or improve performance by not wrapping our class functions in another function unless absolutely necessary. We decided to remove it, though, since we can blackbox scripts in chrome, and it would always return false if the script was minified (as we do in production).