# /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question on this JavaScript Syntax (“What Does This Do?”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/question-on-this-javascript-syntax-what-does-this-do)

Hi all, I've been reading this blog post: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

i do understand the line **fnTest = /xyz/.test(function () {xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;** now but  I've no idea what exactly the whole piece of code is doing. The comments are tough to understand and I was wondering if someone could clarify what exactly do the lines do (in a simpler explanation)?

Comment: Check this one out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/javascript-question

Comment: heys cool. thanks for the link. btw i've edited the question to another question

Comment: If you have another question, please open another question.

Comment: I'd like to know that too... This line is also important though: `prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" && typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ? ... : ...;` **edit** What the hell is this: `/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})`?

Comment: @deceze heys btw why couldn't i just edit this question to another question?

Comment: You did, but I reverted it. Your question already has 4 of 5 close votes accumulated, so it's not really in your interest to keep "reusing" this question.

Comment: @deceze gosh i'd had to edit it faster then next time

Comment: @Pacerier: Or just ask one question for each question... ;)

Comment: @Town obviously i don't mind if there aren't strict limits on asking questions!

Comment: @deceze heys i've changed the question. could we help to reopen the question thx

Comment: @Town  heys i've changed the question. could we help to reopen the question thx

Comment: `/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})` tests to see if the browser will decompile a function to its source code.  If it will, you will get "`function(){xyz;}`", if it won't, you'll get something like "`[object Function]`".  The reason this is here is because the class structure checks for the existence of `_super` as an optimization to not always expose `_super` since it has to wrap the function to do it, and is slower.  As for the rest of it, `/\b_super\b/` is the test I mentioned for `_super`, `/.*/` just means "match any function"