# javascript test function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question on this JavaScript Syntax (“What Does This Do?”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/question-on-this-javascript-syntax-what-does-this-do)

in [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) article i found this:

```
/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})
```

i looked at this and i coudn't figure out how does the xyz passed to the invoker. so i did some similar test in the console:

```
/xyz/.test(function(){xya;}) > false
/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) > true    

/xyz/.test(function(){'xya';}) > false
/xyz/.test(function(){'xyz';}) > true

/xyz/.test(function(){console.log('xya');}) > false
/xyz/.test(function(){console.log('xyz');}) > true

/xyz/.test(function(xya){}) > false
/xyz/.test(function(xyz){}) > true

/fuc/.test(function(){}) > false
/func/.test(function(){}) > true
```

it seems that the `.test()` function converts the argument to string and then does the test. so why `/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})` used rather than `/xyz/.test('xyz')`?

Comment: It's pretty cryptic, but it was suggested (and kind of explained) by one of the first few comments at the bottom of the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its effectively testing that:

`(function(){xyz;}).toString()`

returns recognizable javascript source code:

`"(function(){xyz;})"`

as opposed to something funky that some implementations may return.

It uses `.test` to convert the function to a string then verifies that an internal token (`xyz`) is visible in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the whole article, but this seems to be some kind of browser/feature sniffing.

John's checking if the anonymous `function(){xyz;}` is actually being converting to the string `"function(){xyz;}"`. There are probably browsers that convert it to something else, and that's what he's checking.

However that does seem to me be a bit of voodoo...