# purpose of this javascript test function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question on this JavaScript Syntax (“What Does This Do?”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/question-on-this-javascript-syntax-what-does-this-do)

What is the purpose of this line of code: `/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})`. I have seen it in many pieces of code, but never understood why it's there. What's its purpose? I know that it's a regex function and returns a boolean based on if a match was found.

Comment: To test if function decompilation is supported

Comment: @MikkoMaunu this is an EXACT duplicate, as that question is referring to the same script I got the question from. this probably should be deleted, but i can't now that there are answers. This should be closed then

Comment: I know, that's why I informed you about it. In this context I do not found any reasonable and commonly shared difference between definitions of "duplicate" and "EXACT duplicate". That's why I was not adding "EXACT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks the current environment for the ability to decompile functions. To be more specific: it calls the toString function of *function(){xyz;}* and tests the resulting string with a regular expression that searches for *xyz*. If the js environment supports function decompilation the test for *xyz* will succeed, otherwise it will give false

Answer (score 0):

That checks whether calling `toString()` on a function returns the actual code of the function.

`/xyz/.test(something)` returns true if `something` contains `xyz`.