# Can anyone explain this regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I came across one article by john resig explaining JavaScript Inheritance.
http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

In this post there is a Class implementation code where the starting line has a regexp

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

Can any one tell me what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Search for "regex explainer".

Comment: it assigns a regex to fntest, based on the results of the xyz.test stuff. Beyond that, you can trivially play with this in a browser's JS console and figure it out from there.

Comment: @pst: This one is simpler than that.  The intent of the code appears to be to return `_super` if the function evaluates to true, and `.*` if it evaluates to false.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Which is why I find the title particular irritating .. although the result looks like it will be used as a regular expression itself later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question on this JavaScript Syntax ("What Does This Do?")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/question-on-this-javascript-syntax-what-does-this-do)

Comment: Haha is this a reused exam question from the same professor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fnTest` is used to check whether a method uses `_super` somewhere. To do that, the function is implicitly converted to a string ([`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)) and [`test`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) against the regular expression (in `// Copy the properties over onto the new prototype`).

However, not all implementations really yield the source code of a function when it's `toString` method is called. So this test checks whether the `function(){xyz;}` can be tested against containing `xyz` - if not, the always-matching `/.*/` is used instead of `/\b_super\b/`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two regular expressions.  The first is just `/xyz/`, which is used to test whether the function (coerced to a string) matches `xyz`.  It does.  Then, one of two regexen are returned (in this case the first because the test passes).

The first of them is word boundary followed by `_super` followed by another word boundary which can match at least `"_super"`, `" _super "`  and `word._super`.

The second matches zero or more characters (i.e. everything).