# Javascript regexp test behavior with function

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anybody explain me this behavior? I dont get it... variable a is not touched. Where can be useful?

```
a === undefined // not touched -> on call variable a got exception (this behavior I understand)
/a/.test(function(){a}) // => true !!?
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks much for answers, but I currently have one sub-question.

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/#ig-sh-2

on this piece of code:

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/
```

why John use this?, instead simple

```
fnTest = /\b_super\b/
```

if I understood right `/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})` will be every time true, just like

```
/xyz/.test('function(){xyz;}')
```

Comment: The `test()` method works against a string. Seems to me it is converting the function to a string and is ultimately doing a `/a/.test('function(){a}')`, thus yielding `true`. Now the first line is only an expression, it makes no sense to me, as it should have no effect at all. Where did you get this piece of code?

Comment: @acdcjunior—it throws an error because the OP probably hasn't declared or initialised `a`.

Comment: @acdcjunior http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/#ig-sh-2 6-line

Comment: While [Function.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2) should return an "implementation-dependent representation of the function", not all hosts do. It's not a particularly good bit of code (it will not run in strict mode, but that can be fixed). If the test reveals one of "those" hosts, the match is simply on any character.

Comment: Ah, so its support for older browser. OK. Thanks @RobG :)

Comment: Yes, the code is from early 2008 so IE 6 was still around in reasonable numbers, and probably a bit of IE 5 too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange JavaScript idiom - what does "/xyz/.test(function(){xyz;})" do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911690/strange-javascript-idiom-what-does-xyz-testfunctionxyz-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```
a === undefined // not touched -> on call variable a got exception
```

this is testing if the value of *a* is *undefined*. It will return true if a has either been declared and not assigned a value (in which case evaluation its value will return *undefined*), or it has been assigned a value of *undefined*. If *a* has not be declared or otherwise initialised, it will throw a reference error.

In all other cases, it will return *false*.

In:

```
/a/.test(function(){a}) // => true !!?
```

the expression `/a/` is a regular expression initialiser (or [literal](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5)) that creates a new regular expression as if by:

```
new RegExp('a');
```

which matches an "a" character anywhere in a string.

The [*test*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) method of the regular expression is then called, which will return true or false. The argument to *test* is meant to be a string, so if it isn't it is type converted to a string. That will return a string that represents the function (essentially the actual code of the function). So you effectively have:

```
var re = new RegExp('a');
var s = 'function(){a}';
re.test(s);
```

which will return true (because there is an "a" in the string).

#### Edit

It seems you were asking in relation to this:

```
var initializing = false,
          fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
```

What that is doing is creating a test for function objects based on the result of testing a function object with the regular expression *test* method.

The argument to the test method is supposed to be a string, so according to ECMA-262, if it isn't, it's converted to a string. If the argument is an object, then its *toString* method will be called, and for a function that **usually** returns the code in the function body, but not always and not in all ECMAScript hosts.

For example, built–in functions many return something like:

```
function pow() {
  [native code]
}
```

So what the above is doing is saying "if the function returns the function body, assign the following to *fnTest*:"

```
new RegExp('\\b_super\\b');
```

(Note that the double backslashes are required for this form of regular expression) which will match a string with the word "_super" in it.

And if the function doesn't return the function body, it sets *fnTest* to:

```
new RegExp('.*');
```

which will match any string with zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access an undefined variable (not the property of an object), you will get a `ReferenceError`.

To avoid this, define your variable:

```
var a;

a === undefined; //true
```

Now as for the second example:

`/a/` is a regular expression literal and is the same as `new RegExp('a');` so it has nothing to do with the `a` variable.

As for the last part, `.test(function(){a})`, the function has not been executed yet so the `a` variable (which is not defined) wasn't accessed, therefore no error.

Also, it returns `true` because the `test` function expects a string, not a function, so it does an implicit conversion of the function to it's string value.

Therefore it is like if you were doing: `/a/.test('function () {a}');`

Comment: Executing the function doesn't make any difference since there is no assignment to *a*, so it won't be created as a global variable anyway.

Comment: @RobG That's not my point, it will throw a `ReferenceError` if the function executes. `(function(){a})(); //ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for those behavior is that:

- `a === undefined` ,it shows variable a got exception, because a is not defined, obviously.
- `/a/.test(funcion(){a})` it returns true,because `/a/` create a **regexp variable**,
- inside `test`, `function(){a}` create a function, but it **hasn't been called**, so it wouldn't got exception.

But I don't get the reason for return `true`. = =